# How do I assign specific Terminal profiles to a command in the Automator app?

Tags: terminal, automator

I just used the Automator to create an Application.

Here is the AppleScript:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "ww"
    activate
end tell
```

However, I just noticed that I can set up many profiles in the Terminal App:

[image]

How do I tell the Terminal App to run with some specific profile? Something like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    use profile "my.darkgreen"
    do script "ww"
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> set current settings of selected tab of window 1 to settings set "Grass"
> ```

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122980/37797